# Putting the ASCII values of the characters at the front and back of them in every elements of the list

Tags: python, string, function

The question states:

> write a function in Python that will take a string text as input from
> the user and return the list of unique characters concatenated with
> their ASCII value at the front and back side.

**Input:**

```
"pythonbook"
```

**Output:**

```
['112p112', '121y121', '116t116', '104h104', '111o111', '110n110', '98b98', '107k107']
```

This is what I tried:

```
def function_name(str):
    lis = []
    for i in range(len(str)):
        if str[i] not in lis:
            lis.append(str(ord(str[i]))+str[i]+str(ord(str[i])))

    return lis


print(function_name("pythonbook"))
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the variable name `str` to any other variable name because `str` itself is a keyword and you can't iterate it. While declaring a variable with a keyword it creates conflicting that's why you're getting the error.

```
def function_name(s):
    lis = []
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[i] not in lis:
            lis.append(str(ord(s[i]))+s[i]+str(ord(s[i])))

    return lis
```

Output

```
['112p112', '121y121', '116t116', '104h104', '111o111', '110n110', '98b98', '111o111', '111o111', '107k107']
```

**PS** Don't mix up a variable name with a keyword name

Answer (score 1):

You are taking function parameter name as `str`, later you are passing the value `(ord(str[i]))+str[i]+str(ord(str[i]))` to `str` builtin, but since, `str` has already been used as a variable name, you get `TypeError` saying that `'str' object is not callable`

```py
def function_name(str): #<--- str as a variable
    lis = []
    for i in range(len(str)):
        if str[i] not in lis:
            lis.append(str(ord(str[i]))+str[i]+str(ord(str[i])))  #<--- calling str

    return lis
```

So, the fix is to avoid `str` as a variable name:

```py
def function_name(strng):
    lis = []
    for i in range(len(strng)):
        if strng[i] not in lis:
            lis.append(str(ord(strng[i]))+strng[i]+str(ord(strng[i])))
    return lis
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
print(function_name("pythonbook"))
['112p112', '121y121', '116t116', '104h104', '111o111', '110n110', '98b98', '111o111', '111o111', '107k107']
```